# Model Properties assinged by jquery are null at post in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a dropdown that populates based on selection from another dropdown. Father dropdown when click change event occur and it send the value to populate the data for child grid.  When user clicks on the dropdown, the right selection is made and I can see the correct value in the developer portal. Everything works fine except that when I post the form, in controller I don't get to see the dropdown Selected value that is an int.

```
public class MyModel()
 {
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int  TableId { get; set; }
    public string Round { get; set; }
    public int? InterationId { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<table class="task-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="task-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TableName, "Header")
        </td>
        <td>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.TableName).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlTableName" })
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataTextField("Key")
    .Events(e => e.Change("onNameChnage"))
    .BindTo((List<KeyValuePairVM>)ViewData["Names"]).ValueName
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="task-label">Index Number</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IndexNumber, new { @readonly = true, @class = "form-control", style = "height: 28px; padding: 3px 0px;" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="task-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IterationId, "Iteration")</td>
        <td>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.IterationId).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlIteration" })
    .DataValueField("Key")
    .DataTextField("Value")
    .Events(e => e.Change("onInerationValueChange"))
    .Value(headerId)
     .DataSource(source =>
     {
         source.Read(read =>
         {
             read.Action("Iteration_Read", "standard").Data("GetNameParam");
         });
     })
            )
        </td>

    </tr>

   </table>

   
<script> 


    function onNameChnage() {
        

            $("#IterationId").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();

        }

    function GetNameId() {
        var check = $("#Name").val();
        return { tableName: check};

    }

</script>
```

Comment: "Model Properties assinged by jquery are null at post" How do you post your data? Besides, could you share your table model and controller code ?